# Unable to register git runner on remote network server

Tags: linux, git, server, centos, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to register a git runner on my company remote network server Centos 7 Linux, gitlab is working fine but when trying to register a git runner like this:

1. gitlab-runner register
2. Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):: https://testgitlab.mycompany.com/
3. Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner: $MyToken
4. Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:  [testgitlab.mycompany.com]: testing
5. Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated): test

but as a result I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed
runner=UZqkfhj status=couldn't execute POST against https://testgitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/runners: Post
https://testgitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/runners: dial tcp:
lookup testgitlab.mycompany.com on 192.168.1.123:53: no such host 
PANIC: Perhaps you are having network problems
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this:

```
search mycompany.com
nameserver 192.168.1.123
```

Comment: ping testgitlab.mycompany.com

Comment: Looks like you have that set in your hosts file. Hosts file do not handle subdomains. You either have to list all subdomains in your hosts file or setup a dns

Comment: Alright, i've updated /etc/hosts file. Basically the only thing i did just added result of ping testgitlab.mycompany.com into /etc/hosts file. Thank you, @RisingSun. I was able finally to register my gitlab runner